# Aligning two tables in a line

Tags: html, html-table, inline

I have the following code:

```
<div id="topinfo" style="margin: 10px 320px">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="/images/topinfo/flagpt.png""/>
</td>
<td>
<img src="/images/topinfo/flaguk.png""/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="/images/topinfo/assistencia.png" /> </br>
<img src="/images/topinfo/numero.png" />
</td>
<td background="/images/topinfo/separator.png">
</td>
<td>
<a href='/top-info/sobre-nos'><img src="/images/topinfo/sobrenos.png" /> </a> </br>
<a href='/top-info/contactos'><img src="/images/topinfo/contactos.png" /> </a>
(...)
```

There is more code beneath it, but I dont believe its the problem, just some basic images and links

My problem here is that I want to get them both in the same line, and at the moment, that is not working. I tried using "style='display:inline;'" in the tables and divs, and still did not work. I also tried to "merge" both tables, but they have fixed heights that dont go well togheter.

There is probably a very simple fix, but I am not too professional at css and html yet.

(Screenshot shows what it is currently. The left grafic is a logo with a "float:left;")

[image: screenshot]

EDIT:(also added is what happens when I tried doing the them in the same table)

[image: screenshot 2 same table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it using a single table and the "valign=middle" property to align everything.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's to give others who want the opportunity to answer too.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Try putting the images in the same td as the text, and editing the divider image to be taller.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="/images/topinfo/flagpt.png""/>
<img src="/images/topinfo/assistencia.png" /> </br>
<img src="/images/topinfo/numero.png" />
</td>
<td background="/images/topinfo/separator.png">
</td>
<td>
<img src="/images/topinfo/flaguk.png""/>
<a href='/top-info/sobre-nos'><img src="/images/topinfo/sobrenos.png" /> </a> </br>
<a href='/top-info/contactos'><img src="/images/topinfo/contactos.png" /> </a>
```

Comment: I had tried that before, but it screws up the table alignments, mostly due to being diferent heights. I tried using fix heights, and didnt work out, but its possible I did it wrong. Check the edited question for screenshot.